# In a ring $R$, if $xRy\subseteq I$ where $I\unlhd R$ is an ideal, then $(x)(y)\subseteq I$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I came to the part of the proof that i can't quite crack. If $xRy\subseteq I$ where $I\unlhd R$ is an  ideal, then $(x)(y)\subseteq I$.

Attempt: Let $z \in (x)(y)$. Then $z$ is of the form:
$$z=\sum_{i=1}^nx_iy_i,\quad x_i\in (x), y_i\in(y)$$
Every $x_iy_i$ can be written in the form:
$$\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n_x}r_kxs_k + rx+xs + m_xx\right)\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n_y}l_kyt_y + ly + yt + m_yy\right)$$
where all $r_k,s_k,l_k,t_k,r,l,t,s\in R$ and $m_x,m_y \in \mathbb Z$. I realised that if you multiply any two terms in the two parentheses you get something in $I$ (it comes from the fact that $xRy \subseteq I$ and $I$ being an ideal), except the last two terms $m_xx \cdot m_yy= (m_x\cdot m_y)xy$ which is dont have to be in $xRy$ since $R$ doesn't need to have a $1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result is just not true in general if $R$ does not have a unit.

As an example, $R=2\mathbb{Z}$, $I=8\mathbb{Z}$, and $x=y=2$. Then $xRy=I$, but $xy=4\not\in I$.